# Update all blob columns in all tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mediawiki

We are migrating a wiki system from MediaWiki v1.25 to v1.35 while using a cloned database in the same MySQL server, but in a new Apache server. The issue is that, after doing all the steps mentioned [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Installing_MediaWiki) and [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Upgrading), all the BLOB columns that have a UTF-8 encoded character like á, Ó, é got somehow polluted with the UTF-8 encoded character [U+0083](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0083) just before the afromentioned characters.
Fortunatelly, we found out that it can be solved by doing the following `UPDATE`.

```
UPDATE clone_wiki_db.some_table 
SET blob_col = REPLACE(blob_col, CONCAT(CHAR(0x83), CHAR(0xC2)), '');
```

The problem here is that there are a lot of BLOB columns in the DB. Is there a way to mass `UPDATE` all BLOB columns in the cloned DB? Is there a better approach to do this "cleaning"?

Here are some details of both systems:

***Legacy system (no issues here)***

- MediaWiki 1.25
- MySQL 5.6.29

  - Original DB, not altered in any way.
- PHP 5.4.45
- CentOS 5

***New system (in test stage, with issues)***

- MediaWiki 1.35
- MySQL 5.6.29 *(will be updated later)*

  - Cloned DB
  - Same charset as original
- PHP 7.4.30
- CentOS 8 Stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self answering if anyone falls in the same situation.
Based [in this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/248876), I used a stored procedure, a cursor and a prepared statement to do the job. First, I retrieve all the columns in the DB with a `BLOB`, `TINYBLOB` or `VARBINARY` datatype along with the respective table. Then, by using a `CURSOR`, I fetch every row and build a dynamic `UPDATE` string in order to execute it by using a prepared statement/dynamic SQL.

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS BLOB_CLEANER//
CREATE PROCEDURE BLOB_CLEANER() BEGIN
    DECLARE var_final INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE var_column VARCHAR(25);
    DECLARE var_table VARCHAR(25);
    
    DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT  TABLE_NAME,
            COLUMN_NAME
    FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
    WHERE   TABLE_SCHEMA = 'clone_wiki_db' 
    AND     DATA_TYPE IN ('TINYBLOB', 'BLOB', 'VARBINARY');    
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET var_final = 1;
    
    OPEN cursor1;
    
    bucle: LOOP
        FETCH cursor1 
        INTO  var_table, 
              var_column;

        IF (var_final = 1) THEN
          LEAVE bucle;
        END IF;
                                
        SET @sql = CONCAT(
            'UPDATE ',
            var_table,
            ' SET ',
            var_column,
            ' = REPLACE(',
            var_column,
            ', CONCAT(CHAR(0x83), CHAR(0xC2)), '''')'
        );
                            
        PREPARE stmt
        FROM    @sql;
        
        EXECUTE stmt;
            
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END LOOP bucle;
    
    CLOSE cursor1;    
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

After executing the SP, I changed the charset of the DB from latin1 to utf8_swedish_ci.

```
ALTER SCHEMA `clone_wiki_db` DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci;
```

Finally, restarted the Apache service.

As always, ***be cautious*** when using dynamic SQL (or a prepared statements like this) in order to avoid a SQL injection.